# Combine multiple dataframes returned from TDA-API python library

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the code below that is saving a file for each ticker in my list, but I am trying to workout how to append all tickers into one dataframe and then save to CSV.

```
from tda import auth, client
import json
import config
import pandas as pd
import datetime

try:
    c = auth.client_from_token_file(config.token_path, config.api_key)
except FileNotFoundError:
    from selenium import webdriver
    with webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/capnb/Documents/TDAmeritrade/chromedriver') as driver:
        c = auth.client_from_login_flow(
            driver, config.api_key, config.redirect_uri, config.token_path)

def get_chains(symbol):
    r = c.get_option_chain(symbol)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    ret = []
    for date in data["callExpDateMap"]:
        for strike in data["callExpDateMap"][date]:
            ret.extend(data["callExpDateMap"][date][strike])
    for date in data["putExpDateMap"]:
        for strike in data["putExpDateMap"][date]:
            ret.extend(data["putExpDateMap"][date][strike])
    df = pd.DataFrame(ret)
    for col in ("tradeTimeInLong", "quoteTimeInLong", "expirationDate", "lastTradingDay"):
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], unit="ms")
    filename = symbol + '-option_prices-' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M') + '.csv'
    path = "c:/Users/capnb/Desktop/"
        
    df.to_csv(path+filename)

symbols = ['AAPL', 'GME', 'TSLA','GDXJ','SPY','UVXY','TLT','NIO','RKT',]
for symbol in symbols:
    get_chains(symbol)
```

I've tried applying this solution but I'm lost.

```
symbols = ['AAPL', 'GME', 'TSLA','GDXJ','SPY','UVXY','TLT','NIO','RKT',]
data = pd.DataFrame()
for symbol in symbols:
    tmp = get_chains(symbol)
    tmp.reset_index(inplace=True)
    tmp['Symbol'] = Symbol
    data = data.append(tmp, ignore_index=True)
    
filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('option_chain-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')
path = "c:/Users/capnb/Desktop/"
    
data.to_csv(path+filename)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this to replace relevant code sections.

```
def get_chains(symbol):
    r = c.get_option_chain(symbol)
    data = json.loads(r.text)

    ret = []
    for date in data["callExpDateMap"]:
        for strike in data["callExpDateMap"][date]:
            ret.extend(data["callExpDateMap"][date][strike])
    for date in data["putExpDateMap"]:
        for strike in data["putExpDateMap"][date]:
            ret.extend(data["putExpDateMap"][date][strike])
    df = pd.DataFrame(ret)
    for col in ("tradeTimeInLong", "quoteTimeInLong", "expirationDate", "lastTradingDay"):
        df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col], unit="ms")
    ### ---- changes start here ---- ###
    df['Symbol'] = symbol
    return df

symbols = ['AAPL', 'GME', 'TSLA','GDXJ','SPY','UVXY','TLT','NIO','RKT',]
df_list = [] ### collect dataframes
for symbol in symbols:
    df_list.append(get_chains(symbol))

### concat dataframes
df_final = pd.concat(df_list)
df_final.reset_index(inplace=True)
    
filename = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('option_chain-%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M.csv')
path = "c:/Users/capnb/Desktop/"
```